# Инициализация ссылки в структуре

Tags: c++, инициализация

```
struct A {
    const int& x;
};

int foo() {
    return 42;
}

A a(foo());
```

Программа компилируется gcc, но не компилируется clang https://godbolt.org/z/oaEerdxac. Кто прав и почему?

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'A'

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества куда уж конкретней?

Comment: Следует написать `A a{foo()};`

Answer (score 2):

В стандарте c++17 :

Для структур и объединений синтаксис предполагает использовать фигурные скобки. И называется это [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) *(общая инициализация)*.

```
struct A {
  const int& x;
  const int& y;
};

A a = { 1 , 2 } ;
```

В круглых скобках это называется [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) *(прямая инициализация)*. И она предполагает вызов конструктора. Но конструктор по-умолчанию определён только по-умолчанию, копирования и перемещения. По-элементного нет.

В стандарте c++20 разрешили использовать круглые скобки для общей инициализации. Но компилятор **clang** не успел добраться до этой тонкости, а **gcc** сделал.

Полный список [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) *(видов инициализации)*.